# Flextable Shows Blank White Image in R

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to create and view a flextable object in R or RMD. But even the simplest example is producing nothing but a large blank white image.

I've removed and re-installed the package several times and added "officer" and "officedown" packages but nothing is working. Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(officedown)
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
b <- flextable(a)
b
```

This produces a blank white image.

Comment: What navigator are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm using R Studio in Anaconda, does that answer your question? I also updated R to the latest verison.

Comment: Wow. I just ran R studio outside of Anaconda and it worked. Thanks. Why would that be?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, my first assumption was you were using IE6 but it seems it's not the case